# How to draw a custom shape in the UIView for a table view header section?

Tags: swift, uitableview, calayer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to draw a custom shape in the `headerView` for a given section in my `UITableviewController`. Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        10
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let rect = view.bounds
    
    let bezier = UIBezierPath()
    bezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
    bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
    bezier.stroke()
    
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = bezier.cgPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    
    view.layer.addSublayer(shape)
    return view
}
```

The `UIView` is rendered correctly. I know this because I can see the color of the header sections change from the default color to white. However, the drawing I have done in the `CAShapeLayer` is not being rendered. I am thinking possibly there is configuration missing in the layer instantiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
   class ViewWithLine : UIView {

      override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let y: CGFloat = rect.midY
        let x1: CGFloat = rect.minX + 5
        let x2: CGFloat = rect.maxX - 5

        UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()

        let b = UIBezierPath()
        b.lineWidth = 0.5
        b.move(to: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y))
        b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x2, y: y))
        b.stroke()
    }
 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            5
        }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = ViewWithLine()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view
    }
```